# Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget. - How do I fix this?

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

I am relatively new at Flutter and I am getting the following error message.

Error Message:

```
The following assertion was thrown while applying parent data.:
Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.

The ParentDataWidget Expanded(flex: 1) wants to apply ParentData of type FlexParentData to a RenderObject, which has been set up to accept ParentData of incompatible type ParentData.

Usually, this means that the Expanded widget has the wrong ancestor RenderObjectWidget. Typically, Expanded widgets are placed directly inside Flex widgets.
The offending Expanded is currently placed inside a SizedBox widget.
```

The following is the codes which I believe the error lies:

```
Material(
              elevation: 2,
              color: Colors.white70,
              child:
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                  horizontal: size.width * 0.05,
                  vertical: size.height * 0.02,
                ),
                child: SizedBox(
                  height: size.height * 0.4,
                  width: size.width,
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      _orders
                          ? StreamBuilder(
                              stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                  .collection('VendorOrders')
                                  .doc(_uid)
                                  .collection('CurrentOrders')
                                  .orderBy('orderTime', descending: true)
                                  .snapshots(),
                              builder: (context,
                                  AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> orderSnapshot) {
                                if (orderSnapshot.connectionState ==
                                    ConnectionState.waiting) {
                                  return Container(
                                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                                    child: Center(
                                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                                        backgroundColor: colorTeal,
                                        strokeWidth: 1,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  );
                                } else {
                                  //error is likely from here
                                  return Expanded( 
                                      child: ListView.builder(
                                          itemCount:
                                              orderSnapshot.data.docs.length,
                                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                            DocumentSnapshot order =
                                                orderSnapshot.data.docs[index];
                                            if (current(order)) {
                                              return VendorOrderDetailCard(
                                                  doc: order);
                                            } else {
                                              return Container();
                                            }
                                          }
                                          )
                                  );
                                }
                              })
                          : Expanded(
                              child: Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Text(
                                    'There are no ongoing orders',
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      color: colorDarkBlue,
                                      fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                      fontSize: 16.0,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

I think the error is due to the Expanded widget conflicting with the SizedBox but I am not sure what the workaround is.
I tried to change up the expanded to flexible and sizedbox but to no avail.
I would appreciate any sort of help!

Comment: Does not Wrap your `Column` inside `Expanded` remove it.

Comment: Did you try wrapping column with sizedBox(instead of Expanded)  widget and column items with expanded widget.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Expanded should be child of Row & Column** 
**ListView.builder is auto Expanded and scrollable**,
 so no need to wrap ListView.builder by Expanded. you may try two portions of your code by below code snippet.

```
return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(child:  Text(
          'There are no ongoing orders hfdfhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh',
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.amber,
            fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
            fontSize: 16.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
        ),)

      ],
    );
```

**for list part**

```
return ListView.builder(
        itemCount:
        orderSnapshot.data.docs.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          DocumentSnapshot order =
          orderSnapshot.data.docs[index];
          if (current(order)) {
            return VendorOrderDetailCard(
                doc: order);
          } else {
            return Container();
          }
        }
    );
```

Note : if list data not showing you can set height of list builder wrapping with another content.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `Expanded` inside `Row`, `Column` and `Flex`. Example:

```
Row(
  children: [
     Expanded(child: Text('Some text')),
     Container(),
     Expanded(child: Icon(Icons.add)),
  ]
);
```

So remove your misplaced `Expanded`.

Answer (score 0):

Use Expanded Widget within the column or row widget to solve this code's problem.
You should not be wrapping the column and row in Expanded, which is the exact cause of the error.

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("HomePage")),
      body: Column(children: [
        Expanded(
          child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: 100,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text("item " + index.toString()),
                );
              }),
        )
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```